# On the proof of if a sequence of function converges uniformly on $(a,b)$ then it must converge uniformly on $a$ and $b$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I a trying to find a proof of the following:

Given a sequence of functions $f_n$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on an interval $(a,b)$ where $a,b \in R$ then it converges uniformly even at $a$ and $b$.

I am correct in stating that this is a true fact?

Would someone be so kind to write a proof or give me a link?

Comment: This is not correct. It's true if you assume that $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Hint: Use the fact that $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy on $(a,b)$ to show that it is uniformly Cauchy on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh thanks I need that additional assumption, but I am still unsure how to prove it even with the hint. I don't understand how can we enlarge the radius of convergence, in which step of the proof would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make too much sense to talk about uniform convergence in a point, this is just convergence. What does make sense is to say the seqence is even uniformly convergent on $[a,b]$ if it is on $(a,b)$

Assuming that the seqence is uniformly convergent on $(a,b)$ and each $f_n$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and continuous on $[a,b]$ (some condition like this is needed, as has been pointed out in a comment to your question), let $\varepsilon >0$. By assumption there is $N$ such that, for any $x\in (a,b)$, $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|< \varepsilon$ if only $n, m> N$

Now let's look at the closed interval, e.g. at $a$: we apply the usual trick and add $0$:

$$ |f_n(a)- f_m(a)|= |f_n(a)-f_n(x) + f_n(x) -f_m(x)+f_m(x)-f_m(a)| $$
By the triangle inequality this is bounded from above by 
$$ |f_n(a)-f_n(x)|+ |f_n(x) -f_m(x)|+|f_m(x)-f_m(a)| $$
The term in the middle is known to be $<\varepsilon$ by uniform convergence, if only $x\in(a,b)$. The other two terms can be made arbitrarily small ($<\varepsilon$, say), by choosing $x$ close enough to $a$, since the $f_k$ are assumed to be continuous up to boundary of the interval. Note that this choice of $x$ may depend on $n, m$, but this does not matter, the final result is that $|f_n(a)-f_m(a)|$ can be made $<3\varepsilon $ for the $n,m>N$ with the same $N$ which can be used on $(a,b)$.